# Return a value from a MySQL select with function using a Yii2 Query

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have a Yii2 searchQuery setup which works very well for calculating those records not within the desired radius of a given point.

```
public function search($params)
{
 $query = TrainerExtend::find();
 $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
     'query'      => $query,
     'pagination' => [
     'pageSize' => $this->pageSize,
     ],
 ]);
 $this->load($params);
 $query->having([
     '<',
     'ST_Distance_Sphere(POINT(' . $this->longitude . ',' . $this->latitude . '),
      PointFromText(CONCAT(\'POINT(\',longitude,\'\',latitude,\')\')))',
      $this->radius * 1000
 ]);
}
  $rows = $query->distinct();

    return $dataProvider;
}

public function actionFind()
{
    $searchModel = new TrainerSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    $trainers = $dataProvider->getModels();

    if (array_key_exists('trainerSearch',Yii::$app->request->queryParams)
        && !empty($trainerSearch = Yii::$app->request->queryParams['TrainerSearch']))
    {
        if (array_key_exists('specialties',$trainerSearch) && !empty($specialities = $trainerSearch['specialties']))
        {
            foreach ($trainers as $trainer) {
                $specialties = $trainer->trainerSpecialtiesArray;
                $trainer->match = $this->caluclateRelevance($specialties);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->render('find', [
        'searchModel'  => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

resulting query

```
   SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `trainer` WHERE `gender`='0' HAVING ST_Distance_Sphere(POINT(-123.3836214,48.418248899999995), PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',longitude,' ',latitude,')'))) < 59000 LIMIT 2`
```

Resulting record is bang on for radius calculations, however I need the distance calculated by the geo function as well. I have tried using an as keyword, but it keeps breaking the query.

Comment: check the resulting query   echo Yii::$app->db->createCommand($query)->sql

Comment: That query works just fine...the resulting SQL statement is: SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `trainer` WHERE `gender`='0' HAVING ST_Distance_Sphere(POINT(-123.3836214,48.418248899999995), PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',longitude,' ',latitude,')'))) < 59000 LIMIT 2  
I need to get the resulting distance back to the controller somehow and I don't know hoe

Comment: show the code where you build and exec the query (but uodate the question .. otherwise is really hard read the code .. )

Comment: and the dataProvider  ..  how you use it  .? . show the other code .. ... And why you are using having  ? ( i don't see aggregation function)

Comment: I was using having because I had attempted to use the ST_distance_Sphere function in an 'as' assignment so that I could return the resulting distance...which did not work. The function works fine and so does all other aspects of the application. The only issue is how to return the calculated distance.

Comment: well but how you use/consume  the dataProvider   .. please show me the rest of you code ..

Comment: Not sure how this is relevant to the query

Comment: well .. for me is the same .. the query is sintactically corret .. this query formally return the correct result  .. if you get or not (and how you get or not) the result ... i don't know  .   if you retain is not relevant .. i can do nothing more  ..

Comment: Looking to your code  .. you get the two row in 'find' (view/gridview)?  or you don't have error but  you have no result ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129074/discussion-between-count-zero-and-scaisedge).

Comment: ok ... i' m in chat

Comment: I have posted   a brief answer to summarize the main points of the solution .. hope you rate i t properly ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For calculated  column you must  add the proper  select code in you query

```
$query->->addSelect(["*",
         "ST_Distance_Sphere(POINT($this->longitude ,
          $this->latitude ), 
          PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',longitude,' ',latitude,')')))as distance"]);
```

then for show the result

first you should add a public var in you model eg:

```
  class TrainerExtend extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
  {

      public $distance;  // codice  di stato del codice fiscale 
      ......

      public static function tableName()
      {
      ....
```

and second you can use distance as a model attribute in your views eg: gridview

```
  <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     ......
    'columns' => [
        .....
        'distance', 
        ...
```